# Are their any good way to generate XML file through C# in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to make a xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<settings>
    <typeofsetting>
        <wordname="add" />
    </typeofsettings>
</settings>
```

The `wordname` can be depend on what user need. How I can make a application that user can generate  the XML file of thing they want. Are there any good way to do this?

The `wordname` not user defined it's come from database the application have inbuilt.

Are their any good practice to do this in C# win-forms?

Comment: @steven spielberg is coding, what about film making ? just kidding

Comment: @ Pranay you can't believes a another thing that  i am living in india as same as you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

...

public void Foo()
{
    var doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1252", "yes"),
        new XElement("settings",
            new XElement("typeofsetting",
                new XElement("word", new XAttribute("name", "add")))));
    doc.Save("SomeFile.xml");
}
```

You can adapt this example to fit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

yes

make use OF [LINQ TO XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

one of the easy way to create xml